# How to get average response time IP in linux

Tags: java

I have a code that works for Windows, but due to the fact that there is a cmd.exe, it does not work under Linux, what can be fixed?

```
public static String getAverageTime(String ip) throws IOException {
        String command = String.format("ping %s | ForEach-Object {if($_ -match '(?:Average) = (\\d+)'){$Matches[1]}}", ip);
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                "powershell.exe", "/c", command);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String averageTime;
        averageTime = r.readLine();
        if(averageTime == null) {
            System.out.println("Wrong IP address");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        return averageTime;
    }
```

Comment: try with ```Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);```

Comment: `ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/ping", "-c 1", ip);` Read all lines and match on "/avg/";

Comment: `ping` exists on the different unix operating systems as well, but it is not guaranteed that it will be in the directory `/bin`. For example on MacOS (I know that is not Linux and the question was about Linux specifically) it is `/sbin`.

Comment: Instead of matching the strings using powershell (which is not cmd.exe BTW) on Windows and something else like grep or sed on Unix, you could on both OSes just run `ping addr` and use _Java_ code to match the strings e.g. [String.matches](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))